# How to configure Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) to change keyboard layout with caps lock?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, desktop-environment, deepin, capslock

My system is Manjaro Linux. But I think this does not metter.
In settings panel I cannot make `CapsLock` as keyboard layout changer.
*Please help*.

Answer (score 0):

Install `ibus` into your system.

Run it in some startup script:
`ibus-daemon -drx`

Now little hack. When you bind Caps_Lock to change layout, case will be change too.
To prevent it behavior, need map Caps option.
A one solution:

`setxkbmap -option 'lv3:caps_switch_latch'`

Go to ibus preferences to change required layouts and shortcuts.
When your press Caps it was defined as `ISO_Level3_Shift`. All is done!

NOTE:

Edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` for persistent xkb option

```
Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "system-keyboard"
         MatchIsKeyboard "on"
         Option "XkbOptions"    "lv3:caps_switch_latch"
EndSection
```

---

UPD:

After time I found two other ways, based on independent hotkey listener.
First approach use xbindkeys and xdotool, it have a lag.

```
; layout
(xbindkey '(release "c:66") "xdotool key Super_L+space")
```

Second via D-Bus instead xdotool, described it [here](https://medium.com/@gedweb/linux-deepin-switch-layout-by-capslock-d4a8fea57511)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

LANG=$(dbus-send \
    --type=method_call \
    --print-reply=literal \
        --dest=com.deepin.daemon.InputDevices \
    /com/deepin/daemon/InputDevice/Keyboard \
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
    string:"com.deepin.daemon.InputDevice.Keyboard" \
    string:"CurrentLayout" | awk '{print $2}')

if [[ $LANG = 'us;' ]]; then
    dbus-send \
        --type=method_call \
        --dest=com.deepin.daemon.InputDevices \
        /com/deepin/daemon/InputDevice/Keyboard \
        org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set \
        string:"com.deepin.daemon.InputDevice.Keyboard" \
        string:"CurrentLayout" \
        variant:string:"ru;"
else
    dbus-send \
        --type=method_call \
        --dest=com.deepin.daemon.InputDevices \
        /com/deepin/daemon/InputDevice/Keyboard \
        org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set \
        string:"com.deepin.daemon.InputDevice.Keyboard" \
        string:"CurrentLayout" \
        variant:string:"us;"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Open `dconf-editor`, navigate to the switch-layout key for deepin (it should be `/com/deepin/dde/keybinding/system/switch-layout`) and set it to `['Caps_Lock']`

Comment: no effect...........................addintional length